# How to edit views settings

Tags: views

I created a views. I am not sure what I selected show and Type when I created the view.

After I created the view, I see it is retrieving data from multiple content types. I am trying to edit the view to select the specific content type but i cant find it under edit view page.

Content type that I created name is "xpress". View name is "GlobalSearch". How can I edit the view and select to display only the content type "xpress".

Thanks.
D

Comment: insert a screenshot of your view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to Admin -> Structure -> Views
2. Search for the view that you have created.
3. Do an edit on the view.
4. In the Filter Criteria, add a criteria for content type "xpress".
5. Save the view and that filter criteria would automatically work.

Comment: Filter criteria only shows the fields of the content types. It does not show the content type "xpress"

Comment: Better have swift look on youtube on how view filter criteria work :) I'm afraid you're missing the idea there a bit.

Comment: In the filter criteria search for "Content: Type".

Comment: If that solved your answer, can you please mark this as this answer of the question, so that it would be helpful to other users as well..

Answer (score 1):

admin/structure/views/view/globalsearch/edit

`Filter criteria > type` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Click on Add and search for Published and select yes.

Click on Add and search for Content: Type then checkmark xpress